# Why Favorite and Ignored tags add button text is not visible on Web Applications site?

Tags: bug, design

Just I have noticed on the Web Applications site that there is no text on the *Add* button for Favorite and Ignored tags text box.

See the screenshot below.

[image: Add Icon text is missing]

**EDIT:**

The same thing happens on Meta too.

(Issue is on IE8 browser.)

Comment: The simplest solution is to use a better browser. But, yes, that look like a design tweak is needed. Hopefully Jin will get to it soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **I found the cause of this issue.**

On `all.css` for `IE` browser, below `CSS` is causing this issue that too with the `filter` only.

```
INPUT[type=button] {
    border-bottom: #555 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#888888'); BORDER-LEFT: #555 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #bbbbbb; OUTLINE-STYLE: none; OUTLINE-COLOR: invert; PADDING-LEFT: 6px; OUTLINE-WIDTH: medium; PADDING-RIGHT: 6px; DISPLAY: inline-block; FONT: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; COLOR: #2d2d2d; BORDER-TOP: #555 1px solid; CURSOR: pointer; BORDER-RIGHT: #555 1px solid; TEXT-DECORATION: none; PADDING-TOP: 4px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #efefef 
}
```